# Connection to HP ENVY 4500 wireless printer failed after upgrade 14.10 -> 15.04

Tags: upgrade, system-installation, printing, 15.04

Tried first the following:

*Hardware* > *Printers* says

```
Printer service not available. Start the service...
```

However, Start Service - button is greyed, only Connect - button usable, "Not connected" on lower left corner of dialog.

Tried then *Connect* > *Connect to CUPS server (localhost)*

```
CUPS server error, failed to connect to server
```

Checked via Terminal, if cups processes are there :

```
 $ ps -ef|grep cups  
 root 796     1  0 08:36 ?  00:00:01 /usr/sbin/cups-browsed  
 root 2673    1  0 09:09 ?  00:00:00  /usr/sbin/cupsd -l
 lp   2679 2673  0 09:09 ?  00:00:00 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
```

Then tried HPLIP Toolbox:

HP Device manager says

```
No Installed HP devices found
```

Used Setup device - button, did *Manual Discovery* > *Next*, and printer was discovered. Clicked Next, on textbox

```
PPD File Not found, click browse...
```

Browsed and found Downloads/ppd/hpcups/hp-envy_4500_series.ppd, used it and clicked *Add printer*

```
Printer queue setup failed, Error: unable to connect to CUPS server
```

Any ideas, please ?

**Additional details :**

- The problem occurs after each boot.
  If I then kill the cupsd and start it again with sudo and with same parameters = sudo /usr/sbin/cupsd -l & , printer will be visible again, but only to next boot, below is what I actually do to get this temporary solution:

  ```
  xxxxx@D830:~$ ps -ef|grep cupsd  
  root       700     1  0 15:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -l  
  xxxxx     2432  2311  0 15:33 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto cupsd  
  xxxxx@D830:~$ sudo kill 700  
  [sudo] password for xxxxx:   
  xxxxx@D830:~$ sudo /usr/sbin/cupsd -l &  
  [1] 2442  
  xxxxx@D830:~$ ps -ef|grep cupsd  
  root      2442  2311  0 15:34 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo /usr/sbin/cupsd -l  
  root      2443  2442  0 15:34 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -l  
  xxxxx     2446  2311  0 15:34 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto cupsd
  ```

> For A.B. Open a browser and use this URL: localhost:631. What happens?

- "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:631"

> For A.B. Post the output of this command in your question:

```
grep cups /var/log/syslog*  
Apr 29 15:30:08 D830 ureadahead[202]: ureadahead:/var/spool/cups/tmp/cups-dbus-notifier-lockfile: No such file or directory
```

(This is the only row in syslog after boot)

Comment: Open a browser and use this URL: `localhost:631`. What happens?

Comment: Post the output of this command in your question: `grep cups /var/log/syslog`

Comment: Maybe you should install `cups` again: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall cups`

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/cups/cups-files.conf` and give me a ping with @A.B.

Answer (score 0):

- Open a terminal and execute `sudo service cups restart`
- Turning on the printer
- Open the location `localhost:631` in your browser
- Click *Administration* and *Add Printer*
- Wait a second, your printer should be listed
- Select your printer and *Continue*
- *Continue* again
- Click the button behind *Or Provide a PPD File*
- Select your PPD file and click *Add printer*